# Nonsense comparison at if in bash always returns true

Tags: bash

I've read all the manuals and examples I have found. I've tried it in sh and worked. But I still can't find how to make it work in my bash file.

I've just this code:

```
echo "$#"
if [ $# == 4 ]; then
  #Some code 1º
else
  #Some code 2º
fi
```

(That's just the last try I've done, based on [Testing the number of arguments](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_02.html) )

But I **always** get errors in my 1º code, because the comparison is returning always true. Then, I said ok, let's try the other side:

```
echo "$#"
if [ ! $# == 4 ]; then
  #Some code 1º
else
  #Some code 2º
fi
```

Just negated the value of the expression inside the if, as It's done in the manual I said before. Nothing, It still enters in the 1º code.

I don't know what more I can try, have tried already:

```
"$#" == "4"
"$#" -eq "4"
$# -gt 4
```

And some more based on manuals I've read.

Can anyone explain me what am I doing wrong?

Thank you so much

PS: anyway, there's the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
function backup()
{
  #Some code


echo "$#"

if [ $# -eq 4 ]; then
  rootpath=${1}
  uvus=${2}
  title=${3}
  file=${4}

  path="${rootpath}$uvus/$title/VersionActual/"
  pathbackups="${rootpath}$uvus/$title/VersionesAnteriores/"
  filepath="${path}$file"

  if [ -r $filepath ]; then

    filesfound=(ls -1 $path | wc -l)

    if [ "0" != $filesfound ] ; then

      backup $pathbackups $file

    fi

  else

    echo 'Error 2'

  fi

else

  echo 'Error 1'

fi
```

So this code ALWAYS goes inside the if, then fails cause I'm running it without parameters (`$# is 0`).

If I create a separated script with:

```
#/bin/bash
if [ $# -eq 4 ]; then

    echo "4 parameters"

fi
```

It runs fine!

Update: add a pic about the execution with some parameters

[image: Execution with some parameters]

As You can see, there appers and error about a line inside the "if", because it enters in it, when it must not.

Comment: what are your actual arguments? Are you always supplying 3 arguments to your script?

Comment: I'm calling it with 3, just check it to be sure and then don't execute the code.

Comment: If you're always using 3 arguments, why are you surprised that `[ $# == 3 ]` is true?

Comment: No no, I mean this is what I expect, but I checked if it works when I run it without arguments, and then it still executes the code inside the if.

Comment: I recommend you try to create a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), because with this code you've pasted, I have no way to believe your claim

Comment: This may be part of the problem. Let me explain (well I'll edit the post, it's quite large what I'm going to say).

Comment: So, if it always branches into an error branch because you're not passing any parameters, pass it some parameters. I strongly recommend you throw out this code and start fresh. Don't worry about the details of the code. Think about what are you trying to accomplish, and start with one or two lines that will get you part of the way there.

Comment: The problem is that doesn't matter how many parameters I'm passing to it, it always goes into. I need it don't do it! Let me update with a picture.

Comment: So nice, people stay downvoting, but no one can help. That's really nice of u.

Comment: @BtcSources: I didn't down-vote, but I can see how people perceive too much "noise" in your question - and you _did_ receive helpful tips from several people. Try to pare down your code to the simplest example that doesn't work. Consider use of `set -x` around statements of interest to have bash print debugging information.

Comment: @BtcSources I downvoted _and_ voted to close this question because it was apparent watching you edit and argue with helpful commenters that you had cemented an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) in place, leaving your question broad, unclear, and non-trivially reproducible. Thus, more work on your part is needed so people can help you.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist if I did It was not my intention, and I just edited to correct some C&P mistakes, and add data. If the question was broad, It's because I didn't know which was the problem in my code indeed, but I didn't mind to do it.

Comment: @BtcSources All in all just realize that DV/VTC does not mean "you suck, we don't like you." It _does_ mean, "this question is poorly done or not a good fit for the community," and a big part of that has to do with potential utility to future visitors. There's even a badge here for a great answer (+20) to a "bad" question (-5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you realize this code makes no sense:

```
if [ $# == 0 ]; then
  rootpath=${1}
  uvus=${2}
  title=${3}
  file=${4}
```

You only enter this branch if there are zero arguments, and then you attempt to assign the zero arguments to those variables, which will all now hold the null value.

Your test should be: `if [ $# -eq 4 ]`

This code

```
path=(rootpath . uvus . '/' . title . '/VersionActual/')
```

creates an array with 9 elements, 4 of which are "." -- you want to say

```
path="${rootpath}$uvus/$title/VersionActual/"
```

Comment: You're right, I updated the question. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @BtcSources Don't change the question in a way that old answers no longer make sense.  SO exists to create a library of questions and answers to help future programmers.  That doesn't work if the questions are rewritten after the answers are posted.  Also, if Glenn was right, upvote him.  I just did.

Comment: The problem is still the same, and the question remains the same. It's always going inside the if.

Comment: It's not. This line is `filesfound=(ls -1 $path | wc -l)`, then the problem in this line appears because it's being executed when it must not, because when there're not the parameters needed, `$path` value is wrong. When I execute the script with its 4 parameters, it runs OK.

Comment: If you fix that syntax error, you'll probably find your script works OK: `filesfound=$(ls -1 $path | wc -l)`